# firefox - ajax needs to request same data twice in order to process

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, firefox

I have a simple page (index) that has a `div` filled with comments. It also has a form under it where a user can enter their name and message and click submit to post their comment. I have a php page to handle the process into MySQL, and AJAX on the index page to update the comments without refreshing. My code works on Chrome, but acts different on Firefox.

On Firefox I need to enter the same exact data twice in order for it to load into the database once. The first time it does nothing, if I enter in different data it still does nothing (because that would be the first time for that data), but if I enter in the same data twice, then it will insert into mysql properly and ajax will update the comment div properly.

Here is the script and html on index:

```
<div id="comments">
    <ul>    
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) : ?>
        <li id='comment'><span>
            <?php echo $row['time']; ?> - </span><strong>
            <?php echo $row['user'];?>: </strong>
            <?php echo $row['msg']; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>        
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".comment-btn").click(function() {    
        var user = $("#user").val();
        var msg = $("#msg").val();      

        $.post("process.php",{user:user,msg:msg},function(data){
            $("#comments").html(data);
        });
    });         
});     
</script>
<div class="input">
    <?php if(isset($_POST['error'])) : ?>
    <div class="comment-error"><?php echo $_POST['error']; ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input id="user" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
        <input id="msg" style="float: right;" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Enter Your Message" /><br>
        <input class="comment-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**And here is the process.php:**

```
<?php
include 'comments.php'; // just contains the connection
?>

<?php
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
$msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['msg']);

// set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$time = date('h:i:s a',time());

if(!isset($user) || $user == '' || !isset($msg) || $msg == '') {
    echo "Please fill in your name and a comment";
    exit();
} else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO comment (user, msg, time)
              VALUES ('$user', '$msg', '$time')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
    } else {
        $selectQ = "SELECT * FROM comment";
        $results = mysqli_query($con, $selectQ);
        echo "<ul>";        

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            echo "<li id='comment'><span>";
            echo $row['time']; echo "- </span><strong>";
            echo $row['user']; echo ": </strong>";
            echo $row['msg'];
            echo "</li>";
        }       

        echo "</ul>";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Again this only happens on Firefox. Works in Chrome. Any help much appreciated

Comment: What do you get in the network tab of the console on the first try with firefox? (sent and response)

Comment: @DelightedD0D first time only thing (that's relevant) I get is a GET from http://localhost/adamallard/?user=p&msg=p&submit=Post+Comment#contact

on second try I get the POST from process.php

Comment: not affecting your current issue, but doing `<li id='comment'>` inside a loop is creating `n` number of `id='comment'`, which is invalid, as `id`s are to be unique.

Comment: try like:- ` $(".comment-btn").click(function(e) {  e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Sean good point, I didn't think of that. It is still working correctly however. I doubt it would change moving it from my localhost to online, but could this  cause an issue anywhere if it still works correctly with an 'id'?

Comment: The only issue would come from if you wanted to do something with `$("#comment")`, ie. link to a specific comment, delete a specific comment, highlight a specific comment, etc.. In each of those cases, it wouldn't know which `id="comment"` you were referencing. Not an issue in your specific code here, but has been for other posts on SO. That is why it is always good practice to prevent invalid DOM. In this case, as simple change to `class="comment"` would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default action of the submit button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".comment-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = $("#user").val();
    var msg = $("#msg").val();
    $.post("process.php", {user: user, msg: msg}, function(data) {
      $("#comments").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! are you able to explain why Chrome would not require that but Firefox would?

Comment: it depends on the browser when the action of the form is missing chrome doesn't submit the form but firefox is submitting on the current page